# Related field of a table to another table mysql

Tags: php

> $image1,$image2,$image3,$image4,$image5. The same with the sku variables

```
 for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
   $test_image = '$image'.$i;
   $test_sku = '$sku'.$i;
   if(strlen($test_image) !=0 && strlen($test_sku) !=0){
     array_push($array,$trend,$test_image,$test_sku);
   }
 }
```

I want to check these variables in the if statement. The aforementioned code of course doesn't work. Can anyone tell me how can I check all the variables into the statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be done by using double $:

```
 for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
   $test_image = 'image'.$i;
   $test_sku = 'sku'.$i;
   if(strlen($$test_image) !=0 && strlen($$test_sku) !=0){
     array_push($array,$trend,$$test_image,$$test_sku);
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
   $test_image = 'image'.$i;
   $test_sku = 'sku'.$i;
   if(strlen($test_image) !=0 && strlen($test_sku) !=0){
     array_push($array,$trend,$$test_image,$$test_sku);
   }
 }
```

I think it help full for you

Comment: change $test_image and $test_sku to $$test_image and $$test_sku